# passing value from .net webservice to jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, rowid

When I pass an integer value from a .net webservice to jquery it is returned as a boolean.

My webservice:

```
     <WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function returnRowId(ByVal User As String, ByVal ProgramName As String, Lesson As String) As Boolean
    Dim RowId As Integer
    Try
        Dim ds As New progressTableAdapters.Progress_LessonsTableAdapter
        RowId = ds.InsertFirstEntry(Lesson, Now, User, "", ProgramName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        RowId = 0
    End Try
    Return RowId
End Function
```

Here is the sql code that returns the rowid"

```
    INSERT INTO Progress_Lessons
                  ( Lesson, Start_Time, User_Name, IPAddress, Programs)
    VALUES     (@lesson,@start,@user,@IP,@Programs);
    SELECT     SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Here is my ajax code calling the webservice and capturing the rowid:

```
     function returnRowId() {
    var dataString = {
        User: $('#lblUser').val(),
        ProgramName: 'Conditional Statements',
        Lesson: $('#lblLesson').val()
    };
    var options = {
        type: "POST",
        url: 'cs.aspx/returnRowId',
        data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#rowId').val(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
                          alert(request.responseText);
                           alert(status.toString);
        }
    };
    $.ajax(options);
}
```

When I debug, the Return value in the webmethod is a legitimate row number.  But debugging the value in the jquery code it shows msg.d=true.  Can't figure out why the row value is converted to a boolean.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You call returnRowId from an aspx page. So I guess you don't have a Webservice, but instead you want to call a PageMethod instead of a WebMethod.

Answer (score 0):

The `returnRowId` is declared as `as Boolean`, so the `RowId` is being converted before being written to response.